# Разработка сайта

Tags: html, css, framework

Такой вопрос. Могу ли я сначала сделать дизайн всех страничек html/css, а потом уже к готовому дизайну прикручивать фреймворк для интерактива? (взаимодействия с бд там и остального)

Comment: рискуете сделать много лишней работы и копипасты, зависит от контента и его вариативности

Comment: Чаще всего так и делается. Есть же стандартный порядок разработки: прототип - дизайн - верстка - программирование. 
Но конечно понимание что вы потом с кодом после верстки делать будете облегчит вам жизнь ))

Comment: Подтверждаю мнение, что так и делается. Например для вордпресса, сначала вся вёрстка делается и принимается заказчиком, потом в неё php пишется. Так проще - принять сначала вёрстку как этап. Но не во всех проектах это прокатит. Бывает последовательная разработка по итерациям, например новые фичи к готовому проекту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Могу ли я сначала сделать дизайн всех страничек html/css, а потом уже
>   к готовому дизайну прикручивать фреймворк для интерактива?
>   (взаимодействия с бд там и остального)

Можете

Answer (score 1):

Да. Вы можете сначала сделать дизайн. Потом сверстать     используя html/css, и уже потом натянуть шаблон на движок. Вам решать с чего начинать.